# Jboss 4.2.3 transaction timeout after 10 minutes

Tags: jboss

I have a very long transaction (over 10 minutes) running on my jboss. This transaction fail consistently after 10 minutes.
I changed my jboss-service.xml as follows:

```
<mbean code="com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService"
      name="jboss:service=TransactionManager">
      <attribute name="TransactionTimeout">1200</attribute>
      <attribute name="ObjectStoreDir">${jboss.server.data.dir}/tx-object-store</attribute> 
</mbean>
```

I also changed the max bean age in standardjboss.xml (10 occurrences ):

```
<max-bean-age>1600</max-bean-age>
```

Which is set to 600 by default (10 min) but the issues still occur with 1600.

Some logs :
I've got this thousands of times during the transaction :

```
 2012-10-29 15:57:45,006 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] Lock : http-0.0.0.0-8080-2
    2012-10-29 15:57:45,006 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 >> enterCS: Thread R/W: 0/0 :: Model R/W: 0/0 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
    2012-10-29 15:57:45,006 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 << enterCS: Thread R/W: 0/1 :: Model R/W: 0/1 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
    2012-10-29 15:57:45,006 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 >> leaveCS: Thread R/W: 0/1 :: Model R/W: 0/1 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
    2012-10-29 15:57:45,006 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 << leaveCS: Thread R/W: 0/0 :: Model R/W: 0/0 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
    2012-10-29 15:57:45,115 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] Lock : http-0.0.0.0-8080-2
```

And when it fail :

```
2012-10-29 15:58:12,944 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] Lock : http-0.0.0.0-8080-2
2012-10-29 15:58:12,944 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 >> enterCS: Thread R/W: 0/0 :: Model R/W: 0/0 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
2012-10-29 15:58:12,944 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 << enterCS: Thread R/W: 0/1 :: Model R/W: 0/1 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
2012-10-29 15:58:12,944 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 >> leaveCS: Thread R/W: 0/1 :: Model R/W: 0/1 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
2012-10-29 15:58:12,944 DEBUG [com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.LockMRSW] http-0.0.0.0-8080-2 << leaveCS: Thread R/W: 0/0 :: Model R/W: 0/0 (thread: http-0.0.0.0-8080-2)
2012-10-29 15:58:12,975 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.StatefulSessionFilePersistenceManager] Attempting to activate; id=4spxl-oj441k-h8vp9pzg-1-h8vpcqc2-p
2012-10-29 15:58:13,100 ERROR [org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.EventServiceImpl] Error during sync listener execution
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Could not find stateful bean: 4spxl-oj441k-h8vp9pzg-1-h8vpcqc2-p
    at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.get(SimpleStatefulCache.java:390)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.get(SimpleStatefulCache.java:375)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatefulInstanceInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.java:166)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
```

Can someone help me ?

There is a relative post here but without solution : https://community.jboss.org/thread/159596

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

Go in : "jboss\server\default\conf\jboss-service.xml" line :
1200
(default is 300)

Then

Go in :
"jboss\server\default\deploy\ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml"

find : idleTimeoutSeconds=300

replace with : idleTimeoutSeconds=1800

There is 4 occurences, replace all.

Comment: in jboss-service.xml find attribute TransactionTimeout, and set the value, under com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService